# How to Prevent Page Refresh on Button Click When Submitting Data with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a web application where a button click triggers an async function to submit data. However, the page refreshes every time I click the button, even though I have used e.preventDefault(). Below is a minimal representation of my code.

##### JavaScript Code:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const downloadButton = document.getElementById('downloadButton');
    downloadButton.addEventListener('click', e => download(e));
});

async function download(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevent default button click action

    const videoUrl = document.getElementById('videoUrl').value;
    console.log('Downloading video from:', videoUrl);
```

##### HTML Snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Button Click Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="videoUrl" type="text" placeholder="Enter Video URL">
    <button type="button" id="downloadButton">Download</button>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

##### Issue:

When the button is clicked, the page still refreshes despite using `e.preventDefault()` in the `download` function. The expected behavior is for the page to not refresh and for the data to be sent to the server asynchronously.

##### Attempts to Resolve:

1. Ensured `e.preventDefault()` is used in the event handler.
2. Verified that the button type is `"button"` to prevent default form submission.
3. Checked for JavaScript errors in the console (none found).
4. Ensured the event object `e` is passed correctly to the `download` function.

##### Question:

What could be causing the page to refresh even after using `e.preventDefault()`? Is there a part of my setup or code that I might be overlooking?

##### Additional Context:

- I'm testing this in modern browsers (Chrome, Firefox).
- The script is included correctly in the HTML and is executed after the DOM is fully loaded.

Comment: Sounds like possibly something in your `script.js` is submitting a form on click?

Comment: @SpencerMay this is my production code, perhaps something with my fetch is causing an issue, otherwise i don't think anything is submitting a form. snippet: https://pastebin.com/NczmNSh2

Comment: If possible, kindly set up a code sandbox to replicate the issue. Once reproduced, please share the link to the code sandbox for further analysis.

Comment: the problem lies in the code which you have not provided in the post

Comment: _"What could be causing the page to refresh even after using e.preventDefault()? Is there a part of my setup or code that I might be overlooking?"_ - must be. Your button does not appear to be inside a form to begin with, plus it has `type="button"` (making it a mere "click button", that without additional JavaScript won't do _anything_ on its own) - so there should not even _be_ any "default" action here that you could "prevent".

Answer (score 1):

You should add a `form` as the container of `button` and `input` **without action property**. Moreover, you should add the `submit` type to the `button` in the form. Also, use `addEventListener` to handle the `submit` event on `form`. Then use `preventDefault` in the function that you are calling with `addEventListener`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="test">
    <input type="text" id="videoUrl" name="name">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>

  <script>
    document
      .getElementById("test")
      .addEventListener("submit", myFunction);

    async function myFunction(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      const videoUrl = document.getElementById("videoUrl").value;
      console.log("Downloading video from:", videoUrl);
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: It's better to write **<form>** tag for input and textarea. So, it won't show unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check you server configurations. If you tried the code below, you will see that it works just fine:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Button Click Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<input id="videoUrl" type="text" placeholder="Enter Video URL">
<button type="button" id="downloadButton">Download</button>

<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const downloadButton = document.getElementById('downloadButton');
    downloadButton.addEventListener('click', e => download(e));
});

async function download(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
 
    const videoUrl = document.getElementById('videoUrl').value;
    console.log(videoUrl)
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If we came to the logic, you didn't even add a form. That is, deleting the `e.preventDefault()` function won't make a difference. Things are not being submitted at all, so the problem is 99% in the backend configurations. Check it out!

Comment: Im sorry i don't follow, what on my backend could be making my client refresh? I've never had this issue before.

Comment: If you have a similar problem, share your code. Are you using Express.js or another Node.js Library? Do you have an online version with the same problem so that we can see it, too? All those matter!